# Is javascript module for browser or node

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, package.json, esmodules

Is there a certain way to tell if a javascript module or library is meant to be used on the browser or on node/deno environment?

I know that library authors can use the [browser](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#browser) field in `package.json` to signal that a library depends on browser APIs that aren't available in node environment. Are there any other fields that are used to signal the opposite (i.e. a library can only be used in node).

Specifically, how can one tell, by just looking at the code, if the [Angular library](https://github.com/angular/angular) for example, or [this javascript library](https://github.com/schaze/node-homie) is for node or for browser,  or both?